# Alternative to metamask. Who manages the private key and the ethers?

Tags: javascript, transactions, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

If I don't use metamask who manages the private key and the incoming or outgoing ether?
In this article https://medium.com/@mehradsadeghi/dapps-without-metamask-17528d14e3fa the author shows how to make a connection to blockchain without using metamask. But if it doesn't use metamask how is ether handled? What happens when a user has to send or receive money?

Answer (score 0):

Your Ethereum accounts system is based on public-key cryptography, specifically [digital signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).
Each active Ethereum account is derived from a public-key and has some secret-key known only to the account owner.
The Ethereum account balances, and evermore, the entire state, are known to each and every node in the network.

### Sending Money

When you want to transfer money to a different account, you sign (using your secret-key) a transaction with the transfer details, and you broadcast it to the Ethereum network. The transfer is finalized after a miner node added it to a block.
Metamask is a wallet providing three independent services:

1. Key storage: storage and management of your secret keys.
2. Signing: Transaction signing.
3. Broudcast: Broadcasting signed transactions (I think it does it through [infura.io](https://infura.io/) by default).

You can replace each of those services using various alternatives:

1. Key storage: you can use other wallets, or even other common ways to store you private keys (the key is only 32 byte long).
2. Signing: the [article](https://medium.com/@mehradsadeghi/dapps-without-metamask-17528d14e3fa) you referd to shows how you can sign using the web3 library.
3. Broadcast: you can broadcast your signed transactions through any Ethereum node. You can bring one yourself (e.g. geth/parity) or use SaaS (e.g. Infura/Alchemy).

### Receiving Money

In order to receive money, you don't have to run any software. If John Doe signs a transaction where he transfers Ether to you, all the network nodes will see it (once it is mined) and update your account accordingely.

Comment: the key question for me is how to securely store private keys on devices? For web app in case you are using browser anyway to access app, Metamask (or any other wallet) is great solution. In case you are developing a mobile app, and do not want to rely on any external software, you would need to create your own wallet to store private keys securely. Then you could use stored private keys to sign transactions. The example referred in this medium post is hardcoding the private key, which is big red no no.

Answer (score 0):

I did some reading and as far as I understood,

In order to interact with the Ethereum blockchain you need to be connected to a node.
Such connection is established by a Provider. You can have your own node as such, but it takes a lot of time and configuration to setup and wait for it to sync with all the data on the chain.

Here comes Metamask as a user-friendly web provider. Metamask wraps up an `Infura` Web3 provider under the hood.

> MetaMask (by default) uses Infura, but has the ability to switch to another node provider, even somebody’s own node. We continue to work with MetaMask and more Web3 browser teams. /source: https://infura.io/faq/

If you develop a dApp, the client can connect directly using an Infura provider (in the example, an Infura node inside the Rinkeby network)

```
window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/3123r4sad...'))
```

From now on you can use the provider with your address and private key to make transactions.

> If I don't use metamask who manages the private key and the incoming or outgoing ether?

Now since you don't use metamask with your imported mnemonics(private key + accounts) you manage all of them. Account and private key can be imported as inputs/env variables/secrets etc or creating new accounts programmatically on the go.